# Spring Data Mongo Repository update operation

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Data Mongo repository for persisting my entities. The parent class of all entities looks like this:-

```
@Document
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date dateCreated;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastUpdated;

    @Version
    private Long version; // This is creating trouble while 'update' operation
 }
```

This is how I configure Mongo repositorries and auditing:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = { "x.y.z" })
@EnableMongoAuditing
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MongoRepositoryConfig {
}
```

I am able to save and 'UPDATE' my entities to Mongo until I don not include the @Version field in my entity for auditing.

### PROBLEM

If I use the @Version auditing field in my entity class, while trying to update a entity/document using MongoRepository#save(entity) method I am getting following exception:-

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 1 , "n" : 0 , "err" : "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: test.MENU_ITEM.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('541ed581f39d6f87787067e3') }" , "code" : 11000}
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getWriteException(CommandResult.java:88)
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:79)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.translateBulkWriteException(DBCollectionImpl.java:314)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:189)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:165)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:93)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:78)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$8.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:900)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:410)
```

Why upsert operation is failing when the entity has @Version? From what I understand, the version field is used for optimistic locking while update operation.

The save save methods seems to be trying to do an insert operation instead of update. Is it expected behaviour with @Version?

```
<spring.data.mongo.version>1.6.0.RELEASE</spring.data.mongo.version>
```

Answer (score 5):

Cleaning the Mongo database fixed the problem.

Before I added the @Version Long version, property in my domain class, I had few existing mongo documents in the collection without version property. This was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to save a document on which version is not matching with the document in mongo collection. It is either not set or some old value is set as version. MongoDB uses @version for optimistic locking which means it matches the version of document in the database with the version on the entity which is being saved. It throws an error if there is a version mismatch.

Try below code and it should get you over this error.

```
public void updateUser(String userId, String password) {
    //Before updating a document for specified userId, fetch the latest document from db
    Login userFromDB = loginRepository.findOne(userId);
    userFromDB.setPassword(password); //set the field to be updated
    userRepository.save(userFromDB); //this will overwrite the document in database with new pwd        
}
```

On saving, MongoDB will increment the Version number.

Comment: How can I explicitly update one property of my document ? Not whole doc

Comment: @CandleCoder You can directly use mongoTemplate and perform a update operation in place.